# OpenGL Rendering Within Rectangle

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl

Is there any way I can render sprites, text, etc., but have part of it not rendered so that it is all contained in a rectangle? This would be applied to scroll views and textfields for example.

Comment: See stencil. See clipping planes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a screen aligned rectangle, then using a scissor rect is the best solution. See: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glScissor.xml

Answer (score 2):

A fragment shader set to `discard` any pixels outside of a certain rectangle could work.